# Pointer to Pointer in COM/ATL

Tags: c++, vb.net, pointers, atl

I am quite new in ATL world.

How can I declare pointer to pointer in ATL. Actually I have a handle which I want to pass by address to function. As shown below

```
STDMETHODIMP   Function(HANDLE* hHC)    //HANDLE declared as void * so actual type is void **
```

OR

```
STDMETHODIMP   Function(LONG **hHC)
```

And want to access this function from the VB client.

Comment: Which version of Visual Basic is the "VB client"?  It's quite different between classic VB and VB.NET

Comment: I am using VS 2008 not VS 6.0.

Comment: Post the declaration in the .idl file.

Comment: I assume this is native C++ code if you're using ATL. If you want to call from VB.net, you will need export the function from C++, build a DLL, and call it from VB.net via P/Invoke.

Comment: IDL Declaration:HRESULT OpenHostController(SHORT HCIndex, LONG** hHC);

Answer (score 0):

If you take a pointer to a WinAPI type represented as a HANDLE, which happens to be a pointer, use a HANDLE*. If you take a pointer to pointer to long, use a LONG**. There's no reason to intermix these types or use them for the same purpose, because they are not remotely the same or interchangable in use.

Comment: Thanks I did the same as you mentioned. Now how can I access this function from the VB Client.

Comment: @Imran: How on earth should I know? You asked a C++ question.

Comment: My Mistake, forgot to add C++ tag.